# URL encoding with Laravel and Hebrew

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I'm using slugs in my Laravel project for SEO reasons. The URL is built like this: `https://website.com/page/{id}/{slug}`. I want to allow my pages to be accessed with id only, and match the slug by myself. So if the user enters `website.com/1`, he will be redirected to `website.com/1/slug`.

So I wrote this method in the pages controller:

```
public function addSlug(Page $page)
{
    return redirect('/page/' . $page->id . '/' . $page->slug);
}
```

And in my routes file:

```
Route::get('/page/{page}', 'PagesController@addSlug');
```

The only issue is that my slugs are Hebrew words, so instead of getting `website.com/1/שער-7` for example I get `website.com/1/×©×¢×¨-7`

Is there a way to overcome this?

(Note: The database and file encoding is UTF-8)

(Note 2: I can access the page via `website.com/1/hebrew-slug`. I think the problem is with the redirect method).

Comment: Isn't this browser specific problem? I tested this (not with hebrew but with letters with accents, like `čš`, and it works nicely.

Comment: It happend on all browsers...

Answer (score 1):

I've met same problem and all popular slugs packages didn't work with UTF-8 URLs, so I wrote [my own package](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-russian-slugs). Check it out, you can use it as is if you don't need to translitarate UTF-8 characters to ASCII. Or you can fork it to make some modifications.

Comment: I can access the page via `website.com/1/hebrew-slug` . I think the problem is with the redirect method.

Comment: @Daniel wait for other answers, maybe someone will show you a better way. But I myself never found it, so I wrote the package for my projects. )